# MYSQL: IF having OR condition & REGEXP match

Tags: mysql, database-trigger, mysql-regexp

**Goal**: To block inserts into database table using trigger having multiple conditions

**Description**: Trying to block lots of irrelevant entries in contact table. I have created a profanity table having lot of bad/swear/dirty words and a regular expression filtering URL. If any entry comes to DB having these bad words or URL then it should not be inserted.

**Analysis**: Searched many different solution over SO and could be duplicate but didn't found any answer having multiple condition and regexp in a single trigger condition. Also, not able to create a successful trigger using those answers. While creation, it is throwing error. Please help, thanks in advance.

**TABLE COLUMNS**
EMAIL, MESSAGE

**TRIGGER**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_contact_insert_profanity_check
BEFORE INSERT ON contacts.c
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (c.email,c.message IN (SELECT * FROM profanity) OR (c.message REGEXP '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)?(\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/' ))
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Database Error: BAD REQUEST";
ENDIF;
END;$$
```

**ERROR**

```
    MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as c
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (c.email,c.message IN (SELECT * FROM profanity) OR' at line 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `BEFORE INSERT ON contacts c` (space instead of dot)?

Comment: Why is there an alias anyway? I'm not sure that is supported at all after looking at some examples/documentation.

Comment: Even after removing alias from `BEFORE INSERT ON contacts c` and `ÌF` conditions it is not working as shown below:
`...
BEFORE INSERT ON contacts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (email,message IN (SELECT * FROM profanity) OR (message REGEXP '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)?(\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/' ))
...`
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
END' at line 9

Comment: Found the issue in my SQL, END IF is not having space. But whenever I am inserting a new row(even from phpmyadmin) it is throwing error. Email field does not exist. `#1054 - Unknown column 'email' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the final and correct version of trigger after debugging lot of possibilities and digging SO answers. Was expecting a quick response as it was not that SCI-FI question that other developers were unable to crack.

**Mistake 1**: Space between `ENDIF`. It should be `END IF`.

**Mistake 2**: Missing `new.column` from trigger definition;

**CORRECT VERSION**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_contact_insert_profanity_check` BEFORE INSERT ON `contacts`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF ((new.email IN (SELECT word FROM profanity)) OR (new.message
 IN (SELECT word FROM profanity)) OR (new.message REGEXP '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)?(://)?[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/S*)?/' ))
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Database Error: BAD REQUEST";
END IF;
END
```